# Receiving an error when requesting an exchange

Tags: python

When trying to send a request through requests python gives out a 403 error, although I have fully copied all the cookies and headers from the request that sends the site
exchange - bitget

```
import requests

cookies = {
deleted cookies, but they are in the code
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.bitget.com',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'language': 'ru_RU',
    'locale': 'ru_RU',
    'origin': 'https://www.bitget.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.bitget.com/ru/spot/ETHUSDT?type=spot',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'terminaltype': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'website': 'mix',
}

json_data = {
    'languageType': 6,
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://www.bitget.com/v1/trace/spot/public/getTracerFeeds',
    cookies=cookies,
    headers=headers,
    params=json_data,
)

print(response.json())
```